# I have a 2008 chevy trailblazer that only has 1 low beam headlamp working sometimes none

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, trailblazer

I have put a new Hdm module in and replaced both low beam lights but intermittantly I will have either one driver side low beam or none last night I had none this morning even though I hadnt moved the thing. Im thinking it has to be a short or ground  ANY IDEAS?